# C# Custom TreeNode Align

Tags: c#, treenode

I have a custom TreeNode Control whit

```
DrawMode = OwnerDrawAll
```

Need to incrase distance whit other Nodes if user expand the tree.
In my case, i see this.

[image]

i have added VisualElementRenderer ( Plus and Minus)
and more feature.
but cannot find a good solution for incrase distance.

for example i have try

```
int offset = 20;
e.Bound.X + offset * e.Node.Index;
```

and i see

[image]

But dont are correct.

My tree is:

My Tree.

```
aaa
 |___ Nuova Cartella
 |   |_ Nuovo Documenti di testo.txt
 | 
 |__ aaa.mp2d
 |__ test.mp2d
```

My Code

```
g.DrawString(e.Node.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 40 + offset * e.Node.Index, e.Bounds.Y + 15));



if (e.Node.Text.Contains(".mp2d"))
{
    if (anteprime.ContainsKey(e.Node.Text)) g.DrawImage(anteprime[e.Node.Text], e.Bounds.X+offset * e.Node.Index, e.Bounds.Y + 5);
    else g.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.NoPreview, e.Bounds.X+offset * e.Node.Index, e.Bounds.Y + 5);
}
else 
{

    if (e.Node.IsExpanded)
    {
        g.DrawImage(MireEditor.Properties.Resources.folder_black, e.Bounds.X+offset * e.Node.Index, e.Bounds.Y + 5);

    }
    else
    {
        g.DrawImage(MireEditor.Properties.Resources.Folder_Black_Generic, e.Bounds.X+offset * e.Node.Index, e.Bounds.Y + 5);
    }
```

How to draw correctly?

Comment: `DrawTreeNodeEventArgs.Bounds` is a read-only attribute; try doing something like this:
`Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + offset * e.Node.Level, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);` and instead of using `e.Bounds.X` use `bounds.X`

Comment: You cannot directly control where TreeView places its nodes.  Only indirectly, you can change the Font property.  A larger point size gives you more spacing between the nodes.  You don't actually have to use that font to draw.

Comment: @AlphaDelta Tanks Delta! Work fine whit Rectangle :)